# Определение, создан ли файл программно или скопирован

Tags: c#

Существует ли способ определить, что файл создан программно, а не просто скопирован? Т.е. для работы моей программы я должен знать точно, что файл был именно создан на данной машине.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это можно определить по разности даты создания и даты изменения файла.

Если файл создан программно, дата его изменения не может быть раньше даты создания. А если файл был скопирован, время его создания будет совпадать со временем копирования, а время изменения останется прежним и скорее всего будет раньше, чем время создания.

Comment: Разумеется, всё это при условии, что эти сведения проставлены верно и что речь не идёт о samba и т.п.

Comment: Нормальные файловые менеджеры копируют вместе с датами.

Answer (score 3):

Они все созданы программно =)

И файловой системе всё равно, кто создавал это - ваша программа или файловый менеджер какой-либо - файловая запись от этого не изменится.

Если вы не следили и не вешали перехватчики на функции файловой системы, словно антивирус, то, думаю, вам этого не узнать.

Answer (score -1):

В случае с файлами, скачанными из интернета, и их последующим запуском, оболочка знает, что файл получен из небезопасного источника. Как? А очень просто - на разделах NTFS есть недоступные напрямую дополнительные потоки файла. Думаю, что проанализировав их содержимое можно получить необходимую информацию.

Если же задача более глобальная (напр., пишете антивирус) и есть возможность разбора на уровне секторов ФС - можно, например, изучить logfile файловой системы.